# mysql- subtract values between rows where column values correspond

Tags: mysql, sql, subtraction

I have a table like:

```
Number  |  Event  |  Weight
1            4          150
1            4          160
2            5          200
2            4          200
3            6          190
3            6          195
```

For each row, I would like to subtract from its `Weight`, the `Weight` of another row where `Number` and `Event` matches (if exists). The desired output is:

```
Number  |  Event  |  Weight  | DIFF
1            4          150    -10
1            4          160     10
2            5          200    NULL
2            4          200    NULL
3            6          190     -5
3            6          195      5
```

Is such an operation possible? Not sure if relevant, eventually I would need to turn this query into a `view`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be the result if the table contains 3 or more rows with the same combination of number and event?

Comment: I neglected to note that there will only ever be 1 other match in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join:

```
select 
  t.*,
  t.weight - tt.weight diff
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.number = t.number and tt.event = t.event and tt.weight <> t.weight
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by simply substracting the column in the joined table. When one of the operands is null, the result of the arithmetic operation is null:

```
select a.Number, a.Event, a.Weight, a.Weight - b.Weight as DIFF
from a
left join b on a.Number = b.Number and a.Event = b.Event
```